Is it possible to make an index when *publishing* from orgmode to latex PDF?
I try to make sense of how index creation works in orgmode (or from orgmode), specifically with multiple files in the project. I'd like to know how to make an index for the latex-to-pdf process, but would also appreciate an advice on how to do that for org-to-org publishing.
I know about this question, and the 1st answer sort of works for me, but that's a Latex-centric solution, not well controllable from within emacs/orgmode. Also, it's unclear how would it work for multiple files?
Which brings us back to the matter. I have the MWE, the text of which follows at the end of the question. I do C-x C-e on the elisp expression to fill up the org-publish-project-alist variable. Then I do org-publish and enter latex when prompted.
What I get is a PDF produced from the main file, but without the index:
Wrote <project-dir>/1.tex
Processing LaTeX file <project-dir>/1.tex...
PDF file produced.

...and the index files theindex.org and theindex.inc are actually composed, but are then fed to the similar (regular) processing, which of course fails:
concat: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

In the several files case things work the same way - files are just processed separately. Nothing compound is formed that I see.
That's the 'test subject' MWE I'm using:
* Curriculum Vitae
#+INDEX: CV
#+INDEX: Application!CV

(setq org-publish-project-alist
  '(
     ("latex" :makeindex t
            :base-directory "./"
        :publishing-directory "_latex"
        :preparation-function nil
        :completion-function nil
        :publishing-function org-latex-publish-to-pdf
     )
     ("org" :makeindex t
            :base-directory "./"
        :publishing-directory "_org"
        :preparation-function nil
        :completion-function nil
        :publishing-function org-org-publish-to-org
     )
   )
)

